# Fragment not loading on viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter

this is my pager adapter, i want to load 2 fragment by viewpager and tablayout but it displaying white screen only.

```
public class HomeFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    RelativeLayout headerLogo;

    public HomeFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm, RelativeLayout headerLogo) {
        super(fm);
        this.headerLogo = headerLogo;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Returning the current tabs
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new DoubleColumnMintsList();
            case 1:
                return new MyCircleMain();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

this is inside activity:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        HomeFragmentAdapter adapter = new HomeFragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager(), headerLogo);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        setupTabs(tabLayout);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also facing same issue, it solved try to use this line:

```
 HomeFragmentAdapter adapter = new HomeFragmentAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), headerLogo);
```